# Button onClick() page redirect in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen a few questions similar to this but I nothing is honestly helping me. How do you redirect with a button click in ReactJs?

**Website.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { withRouter, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

//css imports
import './App.css';
import './SplashPage/splashpage.css';

//File Imports
import Resume from "./Resume/resume.js";

//Component Import
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

function App() {
  const history = useHistory()

  return (
    <div className="App">
        { <div id="cf">
          <Button onClick={() => history.push(Resume)}>
            CLICK ME
          </Button>
        </div> }
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I honestly think that I have tried too many options and I've just confused myself even more. From what I understand, the useHistory() function seems to be the correct way to go but as of now I get "TypeError: history is undefined".

Thank you for help!

Comment: Are you using Routing in your Application? Also where do you want the Resume component to render?

Comment: Would routing be the best way to go? All I want to do is create an onClick function that mimics a <a href="...> tag in HTML

Comment: These things can be done in many ways, you can either perform routing, or create a separate page for your Resume component and configure it to serve on a specific url, then on button push you can just open that url with window.open

Comment: I'm looking into routing and I think that way fits the best for my code

Comment: I added an answer using both approaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**: **Without Routing**, you can achieve it using [`multi-entry in webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application) and by creating a separate page in your bundle using [`HTMLWebpackPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/)

```
entry: {
  resume: require.resolve('./path/to/Resume.js'),,
},
 output: {
  filename: '[name].[contenthash:8].js'
},
plugins: [
  // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
      {
        filename: 'resume/index.html',
        inject: true,
        template: 'SOME_HTML_TEMPLATE,
      }
    )
  ),
 ]
```

---

**SOLUTION 2** **With routing**

It is much easier to implement

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

//css imports
import './App.css';
import './SplashPage/splashpage.css';

//File Imports
import Resume from "./Resume/resume.js";

//Component Import
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

function App() {
  const history = useHistory()

  return (
    <div className="App">
        { <div id="cf">
          <Button onClick={() => history.push('resume')}>
            CLICK ME
          </Button>
        </div> }
      </div>
  );
}

const Main = () => (
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/resume" component={Resume} />
       <Route path="/" component={App} />
     </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
)

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the documentation of `useHistory` you will understand the complete cycle of how this works.

Example from docs:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home"); // Here you have to pass the route where you want to redirect 
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

You can study here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: I followed this example and I'm still getting "TypeError: history is undefined" once I click on the button

Comment: Have you wrapped your components in `<BrowserRouter />` or `<Router />` ?

Answer (score 0):

***Updated***

You were pretty close :)

Here is the solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { withRouter, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

//css imports
import './App.css';
import './SplashPage/splashpage.css';

//Component Import
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

function App() {
  const history = useHistory()

  return (
    <div className="App">
        { <div id="cf">
          <Button onClick={() => history.push('/resume')}> <-- Here changed; It will redirect to /resume
            CLICK ME
          </Button>
        </div> }
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Index.js**

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";
import Resume from "./Resume";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
        <Route path="/resume" component={Resume} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: I'm still getting "TypeError: history is undefined". The file path should be "./Resume/resume.js". No luck so far

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-fast-jpv4y?file=/src/index.js I have created an online live demo please check. This is as the way you are looking for :)