# How to hide my NavigationBar Component when on certain paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Been looking around for a fix, can't seem to find something that works here, I've tried using the match tag to match it to a certain page, but it isn't working correctly. pretty lost here.

```
  return (
<React.Fragment>
  <Router>

    {/* <NavigationBar /> PLACE PREFERRED NAVIGATION IN LINE BELOW */}
    <NavigationBar />
 



    <AuthProvider>

      <Switch>

        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/map" component={MapPage} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/feedback" component={Feedback} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/resources" component={Resources} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/academic" component={Academic} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/career" component={Career} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/financial" component={Financial} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/physical" component={Physical} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/psycho" component={Psycho} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/social" component={Social} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/spiritual" component={Spiritual} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/badges" component={Badges} />
        <Route exact path="/404" component={NotFoundPage} />
        <Route exact path="/underConstruction" component={pageUnderConstruction} />
        <Redirect to="/404" />


      </Switch>

    </AuthProvider>

  </Router>

</React.Fragment>
```

)

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the useLocation hook by react router Dom.

You would import the hook: import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

```
const location = useLocation()
```

Then in the component you want `style={{ display: location.pathname === '/' ? 'none' : 'block' }}`

Answer (score 0):

***Updated***

Here is solution:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory()

{allowedRoutesNavbarToShow.includes(history.location.pathname) && (
    <Navbar />
)}
```

---

To update the browser history do following steps:

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Something} />
```

**Something.js**

```
export default function Something(props) {
  function handleClick() {
    props.history.push("/somewhere");
  }

  return (
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to Somewhere</button>
  );
}
```

Visit to see full code and live working solution:
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-flower-h9x8r?file=/src/index.js)

Happy coding :)

Comment: i've done your fix and it works thanks!, no navbar on login, but all pages where it needs to be logged on need to be refreshed first, is there a way to update the browser history for each click without refreshing?

Comment: Hmm, i guess this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66972032/10427807 answer will solve your query. This is my another answer. Please have a look. Let me know.

Comment: I have updated for you my answer according to your query. Check please. I have created a few components `Login` & `PrivatePage`. Visit to see the live `CodeSandbox` demo.